# RabbitMQ batching messages

Tags: rabbitmq

Does RabbitMQ support sending of a batch of messages at producer end and consuming a batch of messages at consumer end ? Like Kafka which stores the messages produced in batches till linger.limit is reached or till the batch is full ! Does RabbitMQ also support batching at producer side ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the consumer side, the closest you can get is [consumer prefetch](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html)

For producer side, as far as I'm aware, batching is not supported.